# How can prototype inner array get the variable in the prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Just like the example shown below, how can I pass the value of `this.a` into the array of `b`?

```
function Foo(){

};
Foo.prototype={
  bar:function(){
    this.a=1;
  },
  b:[this.a]
}
```

Comment: Your code sample does not work semantically - there's an extra comma where there should not be. Is this a copy paste error?

Comment: @doppelgreener but that's not OP asked . `where is the error `

Comment: What do you exactly want ? How do you want to use b ?

Comment: @doppelgreener, yeah, you are right, there is a comma behind the array.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, this original code is lengthy and I just simplified it as this one. The array b is not an one item array, but one of the items will refer to the variable defined in function bar. And I just could not realize it.

Comment: It's a bad idea to overwrite the Foo.prototype with an object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have the `foo.b` expression to have as value `[foo.a]`, then you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
function Foo(){
};
Foo.prototype={
    bar:function(){
      this.a=1;
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'b', {
  get: function(){ return [this.a]; }
});

var foo = new Foo();
console.log("before bar():", foo.b);
foo.bar();
console.log("after bar():", foo.b);
```

But why not just define `b` as a function and access it normally ?

Comment: OP wanted to set property of b to be  `this.a` where a is equal to 1.

Comment: inside the method we usually use `this.property` he also want to use `this.property` in properties.

Comment: @Mahi This makes no sense, as it could be just `b:[1]`

Comment: suppose the value of `a` changed . then `b` value also be changed using `b:[this.a]` ? but if you assign just `b:[1]` then b value is always same

Comment: My answer covers this goal. Which is very bad practice.

Comment: but he wanted to know can we write `this.a` in properties or not ?? since it gives syntax error i think

Comment: It seems my question is quite unclear for I did not post the original code which is a bit lengthy, now I copy the code into jsfiddle to make it clear. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mqt1yceb/). Array b functions the same as array dayInMonth.